# update matching column value in anywhere in database sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, update

I have **assetid** column in multiple table in my Database and Asset(main) table

I want to update all occurences of tables in all occurences of inserts in database **assetid** column where value has **1020** to **1**

```
update AdminInterests set assetid = 1 where 1020
```

I just want to how to apply this update for entire database all tables with one query

Comment: do you mean to say that you want update all table which ever has column assetid where value has 1020 to 1

Comment: yes I just want to how to apply update for entire database all tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to generate and execute a dynamic statement using information from system catalog views. It's important to note, that such an update may fail, if `assetid` column is a primary key or has constraints in some of the tables.

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)

SELECT @stm = (
    SELECT CONCAT(
        ' UPDATE ', QUOTENAME(sch.[name]), '.', QUOTENAME(tab.[name]), 
        ' SET ', QUOTENAME(col.[name]), ' = 1',
        ' WHERE ', QUOTENAME(col.[name]), ' = 1020;'
    )
    FROM sys.columns col
    JOIN sys.tables tab ON col.object_id = tab.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas sch ON tab.schema_id = sch.schema_id
    WHERE col.[name] = 'assetid'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') 

PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

SQL Server (and most other relational database systems) store information about the tables, views, procedures etc. that have been created in a set of internal tables. These are collectively known as the [catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/catalog-views-transact-sql). Specifically there are ones for schemas, tables and columns. We are allowed to read the catalog from code we write.

When a client passes SQL to a server the query is just a text string. So if we can generate a string of the correct format we can pass it to the server and it will be executed. The SELECT statement above generates such a string using the information available in the catalog.

Rather than write a loop that processes one table each pass the code constructs a single string containing all required statements. Each statement is terminated by the semicolon at the end of the literal `' = 1020;'`. The statements are concatenated using a trick of how `FOR XML` constructs its output. In newer versions of SQL Server [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) could have been used instead.

The `print` statement is just to aid debugging.

Finally the `exec` submits the generated string to SQL Server for execution.

Comment: WOW it worked thanks. Quite hard to understand what is going on